# Statistical method(s) to employ to find best features given a number of features

Tags: feature-selection, feature-weighting

I am working on an anomaly detection application that uses keystroke dynamics.

This is the pool of features that I have to my disposal:

1. hold time = R(i) - P(i)
2. key-up to key-down = P(i+1) - R(i)
3. key-up to key-up = R(i+1) - R(i)
4. key-down to key-down = P(i+1) - P(i)
5. key-down to key-up = R(i+1) - P(i)

Where,

- P(i) is the press time of the current key
- R(i) is the release time of the current key
- R(i+1) is the release time of the consecutive key
- P(i+1) is the press time of the consecutive key

I am aware that the "best" features will be the ones with high variance.

What statistical method(s) can I employ for selecting the "best" features?

Comment: If you believe that the best features are the ones with the highest variance, you can just calculate their variances and sort them. But I don't understand why you believe this.

Answer (score 0):

You could employ a GLM that calculates the internally importance of each feature, for example [lasso](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lasso_(statistics)) or [ridge](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat857/node/155). The most common one, as far as I'm aware is lasso.

You might also want to read [this](https://beta.vu.nl/nl/Images/werkstuk-fonti_tcm235-836234.pdf) which explains the procedure with more detail. Or [this](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/01/complete-tutorial-ridge-lasso-regression-python/) excellent tutorial which explains both lasso and ridge and how they are used in python.